# Do these functions have the same domain: $y=\ln (x^2)$ and $y=2\ln(x)$

Tags: logarithms

I believe the domain of the first one has all the $x\in\mathbb{R}$ different from $0$ and the second is $x>0$, but aren't these two functions equal?

Comment: By $E$ do you mean the domain (where the function is defined)?  If yes, then you've found the correct $E$ (for both functions), and they are considered different functions as they have different domain.(Even though the value of the two functions are the same on the common domain).

Comment: What does 'E' mean?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it understandable. OP: check if this is what you meant.

Comment: both functions are not equal

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have $\ln(x^2)=2\ln(|x|)$ for $x\ne 0$